# How to change mapView on pressing a button in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a button in my mapView when I press the button it should change the map type.

It's easy to use three buttons for three types of maps but how I can perform this action by pressing the button?

It should change the view to hybrid then again satellite and standard.

Comment: You use a property to remember the current state and also to update the text of the button.

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht check out the answer below i was using this method but inside button thats why i was getting error

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple counter for this problem.

```
var mapTypeCounter = 0
func changeMapType() { 
    if mapTypeCounter == 0{

        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        mapTypeCounter = mapTypeCounter + 1 
    } else if mapTypeCounter == 1 {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
        mapTypeCounter = mapTypeCounter + 1 

    } else if mapTypeCounter == 2 {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid
        mapTypeCounter = 0
    }

}
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by @TheTiger, you could also directly compare the MapTypes, this way you wouldn't need a counter.

Comment: thanks its working I was actually using this method but directly in the button and it was changing the value of var to 0 on pressing button.

Comment: Did you put mapTypeCounter definition in the button method?

Comment: You can directly compare the current map type instead of this extra counter variable. if `mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard {mapView.mapType == MKMapType. Satellite}` ... like this.